# Need Solution for SQL query

Tags: sql

My SQL query is ,

```
SELECT 
    T.TAX_NAME,A.TAX_AMT_ID,A.TAX_MAP_ID,A.EFFECTIVE_FROM 
FROM 
    MAS_TAX T   
INNER JOIN  
    MAS_TAX_MAP M ON T.TAX_ID = M.TAX_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    MAS_TAX_AMOUNT A ON M.TAX_MAP_ID = A.TAX_MAP_ID 
WHERE  
    EFFECTIVE_FROM <= GETDATE()
```

I am getting output for the above query is:

```
TAX_NAME    TAX_AMT_ID  TAX_MAP_ID  EFFECTIVE_FROM
-------------------------------------------------------
Income Tax  12     5        02-06-2014
Service Tax 16     4        02-06-2014
Gift Tax    3      1        29-05-2014
Gift Tax    2      1        28-05-2014
Gift Tax    4      1        27-05-2014
```

But I need to get below output. Can any one help me?

```
TAX_NAME    TAX_AMT_ID  TAX_MAP_ID  EFFECTIVE_FROM
-------------------------------------------------------
Income Tax  12     5        02-06-2014
Service Tax 16     4        02-06-2014
Gift Tax    3      1        29-05-2014
```

Comment: What DB are you using? SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, ...? Not all DB have the same functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the most recent record.  You can do this in SQL Server using `row_number()`:

```
select TAX_NAME, TAX_AMT_ID, TAX_MAP_ID, EFFECTIVE_FROM
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tax_name order by effective_from desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

For your particular query:

```
SELECT T.TAX_NAME, A.TAX_AMT_ID, A.TAX_MAP_ID, A.EFFECTIVE_FROM
FROM (SELECT T.TAX_NAME, A.TAX_AMT_ID, A.TAX_MAP_ID, A.EFFECTIVE_FROM,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.TAX_NAME ORDER BY A.EFFECTIVE_FROM DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MAS_TAX T INNER JOIN
           MAS_TAX_MAP M
           ON T.TAX_ID = M.TAX_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           MAS_TAX_AMOUNT A
           ON M.TAX_MAP_ID = A.TAX_MAP_ID 
      WHERE EFFECTIVE_FROM <= GETDATE() 
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```